# XCOM 2 crashes with Pure Virtual Function call, GIsRunning == 1

Tags: technical-issues, xcom-2

This is a well-known bug, and I have read just about everything there is to find. It seems to occur in other games running on Unreal Engine too, but in XCOM 2 it happens so often that the game is simply not fun any more. It can happen whenever, but usually when in the base or returning to base.

Things I read about that might have worked for some and that I tried so far:

- disabling all DLCs: makes it better, but doesn't completely go away
- setting my swap file size manually to three times my RAM size (=3*16GB): doesn't help at all
- I don't have mods
- I have Windows 10 and a Geforce GTX 970 with latest drivers

Is there any remedy for these annoying crashes?

Comment: I was never able to completely fix it, but I was able to mitigate it by avoiding the bigger mods.  I realize you have no mods, so that doesn't help you.  However, my point is that I suspect the bug has something to do with the amount of memory the game is consuming vs how much is available on your system.  Perhaps, try closing down as many background processes as you can to free up system memory?  Don't have any browsers or other programs running at the same time as you play.  I have no idea if it will help, but it seems like you've covered the "known" solutions already.

Comment: @Steve-O What's weird is that it runs on my Lenovo Yoga (with lower specs) without crashing. Everything takes ages to load and the framerate is not enjoyable, but I've even succeeded in continuing some savegames that were always crashing on my main machine.

Comment: FWIW, the crashes are completely gone in War of the Chosen, even with all DLCs!

Comment: @FelixDombek - Are you saying that purchasing War of the Chosen actually eliminated the pure virtual function bug in the main game? I've been getting this stupid error in the campaign for forever. I've tried literally everything.

Comment: @disflux nope, just the WotC campaign doesn't have them